# How to create an JSOUP element from byte array image (Load from Database)

Tags: java, image, email, jsoup

I'm reasonable new for JSOUP, I believe most of JSOUP user is using JSOUP to parse html content (load from Internet URL) into text or some other JOPO.

But I'm trying to use JSOUP to create html elements to create dynamic html email content in rich text.

I don't find lots of examples to create dynamic html elements (for example, graphics, logo etc.) which load from database that stored as byte array format.

If any one has experience in this sub, please share me some example.

Plenty appreciation.